# How to display numbers with scientific notation in jquery-inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery-inputmask

I am using the jquery-inputmask plugin to handle integer/float numbers, my options for masking are

```
{ allowMinus: true, rightAlign: false, digits: 3 }
```

Problem is when the user inputs a large value like:

**123456789012345678901234567890**

this gets saved with an exponential like:

**1.2345678901234568e+29**

Now when I want to set this number: *1.2345678901234568e+29*  as a value for the input the masking is applied so this number gets transformed to:

**+291.2345678901234568**

Is there an option for how I can show big numbers like this using the inputmask plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that reason you can use BigInt:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint

Answer (score 1):

You know in JavaScript you can only store 53bit as a number. for solve this problem you can use this solution ([Add Very Large Numbers](https://github.com/niinpatel/addVeryLargeNumbers)) or ([BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt))

**BigInt** : BigInt is a built-in object that provides a way to represent whole numbers larger than 2^53, which is the largest number JavaScript can reliably represent with the Number primitive.